# javascript error "no item selected" for a moment on web page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and I have a problem, I'm training javascript with HTML and when the page loads, for a brief moment, an error pops with the message "no item selected", the code is the following:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var defaultBorderStyle = "solid";
        var borderStyle;
        window.addEventListener("load",loadDefault,false);
        function loadDefault() {
            console.log("Loading default border parameters.");
            borderStyle = document.getElementById("borderStyle");
            borderStyle.value = defaultBorderStyle;
            borderStyle.addEventListener("change",updateBorderStyle,false);
        }
        function updateBorderStyle(event){
            console.log("Border Style: "+event.target.value);
            var borderStyle = document.getElementById("borderPreview");
            borderStyle.style.borderStyle = event.target.value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="borderStyle">Border Style:</label>
        <select id="borderStyle" style="width:175px;">
            <option value="dotted">Dotted</option>
            <option value="dashed">Dashed</option>
            <option value="solid" selected>Solid</option>
            <option value="double">Double</option>
            <option value="groove">Groove</option>
            <option value="ridge">Ridge</option>
            <option value="inset">Inset</option>
            <option value="outset">Outset</option>
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="hidden">Hidden</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        
        
    </div>
    <div id="previewBox">
        <div id="borderPreview"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The error pops for just a moment, I had to record the screen to print it, and when the page finish loading it disappears:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY51F.png)

Comment: [I don't see any such error](https://jsfiddle.net/ned89tpv/).

Comment: same here i also dont get error

Comment: I can NOT see any error like `no item selected` when i run your code. Are you sure you have this error in the console ?

Comment: Uh, that's not an error. It's just the console saying that it's not attached to anything yet ("no item") because it's still initiating the loading of the page.

Comment: hmmm, thank you, I think it was something that needed to be treated...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different method of placing that listener do run only after the DOM's content has loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    function loadDefault() {
            console.log("Loading default border parameters.");
            borderStyle = document.getElementById("borderStyle");
            borderStyle.value = defaultBorderStyle;
            borderStyle.addEventListener("change",updateBorderStyle,false);
        }

        function updateBorderStyle(event){
            console.log("Border Style: "+event.target.value);
            var borderStyle = document.getElementById("borderPreview");
            borderStyle.style.borderStyle = event.target.value;
        }
}
```